# Nginx log configuration doesn't forward SEO's search keywords

Tags: nginx, awstats

I'm trying to make my stats with `awstats-7.7`.
Everything works fine.
Now I'm trying to use google, type a keyword that brings me to my site.
Then I trace the log to see where I come from, and the keywords.
Here's the (important) log line output:

```
www.mysite.fr - www.mysite.fr - 7.24.15.16 - - [28/Nov/2018:07:45:31 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27636 "https://www.google.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

As you can see, in the `/var/log/nginx/proxy-access.mysite.log` there's no information about search. I'm probably missing a directive, but I dont know which one, here's my website Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name www.mysite.fr;

  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-access.mysite.log proxylog;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-error.log error;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/www.mysite.fr/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/www.mysite.fr/privkey;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/www.mysite.fr/chain;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
    proxy_pass http://acmetool;
  }

  location / {
    include denied_clients;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://apache/;
  }
}
```

Which directive am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't missing anything in your configuration.

The problem is that *browsers* can be configured to not send complete referer URLs. For instance, Firefox has [numerous settings](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Referrer) to control when to send a referer and how much of it to send. Chrome strips the path from the referer when the request is to a different site, and users may be using an extension for further control.

Proxies can also strip referer information as well for security reasons, even if browsers send it.